# Is there a auto mapping for spring pageable/sort with mapstruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I like to use mapstruct, but i can't find out: is there a function to transform a Sort in Pageable for the mapped dto pageable to the entity pagable?

Links:

Pagable: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html

Sort: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html

Story:

There is a request:

```
@GetMapping("find")
public List<DTO> findAll(final Pageable pageable) {
    return mapper.map(repository.findAll(pagable));
}
```

And the Repository:

```
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {
   Page<Entity> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

If I don't want to expose the entity column name so i map the column.
Eg:

```
@Mapper
public interface DTOMapper {

    @Mappings({
       @Mapping(source = "make", target = "manufacturer"),
    })
    DTO toDto(Entity entity);
}
```

now the API/Returnvalue has `manufacturer`. The usage of `manufacturer` for the sort-request (included in pageable) instead of `make` is the possible: `sort=manufacturer;asc`.

But must it not be `sort=make;asc`, or can the `JpaRepository` handle it?

So is there a simple way to transform the pageable from the request to the right pageable (with the right sort)?

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 23):

Well - answering to your question "is there a simple way to transform pageable from the request to the right pageable".

If you want to convert retrieved pageable content from db entities with prepared mapper you could use the following approach:

```
repository.findAll(pageable).map(myMapper::toDto)
```

The pageable abstraction has the `map` method:

> Returns a new Page with the content of the current one mapped by the given Function.

I understand that in your case you would like to modify also the `Sort` parameters from/to request according to prepared mapping (modify parameters naming when request is executed and inverse names when response is returned in order to correctly execute it by JPA repository).

Unfortunately in this situation I affraid you have to prepare you own cusom `map` method. What I suggest you could create very similar method but you could extends the logic and modify/create new `Sort` according to provided `@Mappings` annotation(s) to your mapper which will base on the mapstruct mappings definitions. It requires some kind of Java reflection knowledge but with this approach you could create very flexible and universal mapper (it is a good idea to create extension for MapStruct if you are interested).

Hope this help.